# Case when for multiple conditions

Tags: sql

Trying to query a data set with multiple conditions

Table setup:

| car_key | tasktype | ticket_created | ticket_completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | created | timestamp | timestamp |
| 1 | finished | timestamp | timestamp |
| 1 | created | timestamp | timestamp |
| 3 | finished | timestamp | timestamp |
| 5 | created | timestamp | timestamp |
| 5 | finished | timestamp | timestamp |

Basically I want to see the time difference between (tasktype=created, ticket_created timestamp) vs. (tasktype=finished, ticketcompleted timestamp). I'm only looking for data in the last month so if a ticket was created 3/30 and finished 4/2 then I'd just return a null value (ex is car_key=3). I'd want to see this data in a new column.

Is case statement the best way to set this up? The table is ordered on car_key, ticket_created, ticket completed.

I'm not even sure how to start this, I dont need an answer, just a sense of direction here.

Using the ex , I'd like to see the following:

| car_key | tasktype | ticket_created | ticket_completed | day_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | created | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | finished | 2023-04-02 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | null |
| 1 | created | 2023-04-05 00:00:00 | 2023-04-05 00:00:00 | null |
| 3 | finished | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | null |
| 5 | created | 2023-04-05 00:00:00 | 2023-04-05 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 5 | finished | 2023-04-10 00:00:00 | 2023-04-010 00:00:00 | null |

Comment: I don't quite follow your data. car_key 1 has 2 created task_types and one finished tasktype. What is the relationship between created and finished? The way I read it is that car_key 1 started, then finished, then finished again. Is the day_diff just the difference between the created's ticket_created date and the soonest completed ticket_created date?

Comment: @LordBaconPants basically the tasks created/finished are regarding repairs. Unfortunately their is no repair ID. So the data would only say a repair has been initiated (tasktype =created at ticket created timestamp). And I'd like to see the datediff for the repair ( tasktype=finished at ticketcompleted timestamp) The assumption is that these in chronological order. I'm trying a lag function at the moment, that might be the way to go but still open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion: Joining the finisheds on to the created and taking the datediff from that:

```
SELECT *
   , DATEDIFF(DAY, cars.ticket_created, completed.ticket_created) AS 
datediff
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN cars completed
    ON completed.car_key = cars.car_key
       AND completed.ticket_created >= cars.ticket_created
       AND completed.tasktype = 'finished'
       AND cars.tasktype = 'created';
```

Major weakness here though is that if you have 2 "finished" to a "created" it will double it up.

Also, it may not be performant over large data sets, depending on your speed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data and table structure posted, it looks like this is an audit trail kind of table.  And also based on the data, it looks like you just might have inherited an 8-humped camel of a code base, so tip of the hat to you for taking on that project.  Been there, done that!

But anywhoo, the following algorithm, written in psuedo-code, should do what you need.  I leave it to the OP to write the actual code, as per the original question.

1. Create `data_set_1` as a sub-set of filtered data.  The idea here is to end up with a virtual table containing just `car_key`, `ticket_created`, and `ticket_completed`.  For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    T1.car_key as car_key, 
    T1.ticket_created as ticket_created, 
    T2.ticket_completed as ticket_completed
FROM 
    table_name1 T1, 
    table_name1 T2
WHERE
    T1.car_key = T2.car_key AND
    T1.tasktype = 'created' AND 
    T2.tasktype = 'finished'
ORDER BY T1.car_key, tasktype DESC
```

2. Iterate over all records in `data_set_1` and calculate `day_diff` as something like: `data_set_1.ticket_completed` - `data_set_1.ticket_created`.
3. Transform the results from step 2 into a value representing the number of days.

You could accomplish this all with a single SQL query (assuming you're using SQL) by using `DATEDIFF` and other SQL built-in functions.  But, I leave that to the OP.